# Can $\kappa$-club is defined for any class of ordinals?

Tags: ordinals, proof-theory

In reading "Proof Theory - The First Step into Impredicativity", I'm stuck at Thm. 3.2.19.

> 3.2.19 Theorem Let $\kappa$ be a regular ordinal. A class $M\subseteq On$ is $\kappa$-club iff $en_M$ is a $\kappa$-normal function.

And in "$\Leftarrow$" part of the proof,

> Because of $\kappa\subseteq dom(en_M)$ we obtain $otyp(M\cap\kappa)=\kappa$.

My main question is "Why is this true?".
In my opinion, if $M\cap\kappa=\emptyset$, $\kappa\subseteq dom(en_M)$ may be true and $otyp(M\cap\kappa)=\kappa$ never. Moreover this situation is caused because $\kappa$-club is defined for any class of ordinals in this book. In order to be unbounded in $\kappa$, $M$ have to contain ordinals less than $\kappa$(, so $otyp(M\cap\kappa)=\kappa$). $M$ containing only ordinals over $\kappa$, however, may make it true that $en_M$ is a $\kappa$-normal function.

Comment: What is $en_M$?

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of explanation. $en_M$ is a enumerating function of $M$ as $(M, \in)$ from order -type of $M$ to $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the book at hand, but if I recall correctly the following definition of normality is used:

> A function $f$ is $\kappa$-normal if $(i)$ the domain of $f$ is $\kappa$, $(ii)$ the range of $f$ is contained in $\kappa$, $(iii)$ for $\alpha<\beta<\kappa$ we have $f(\alpha)<f(\beta)$, and $(iiv)$ for $\lambda<\kappa$ limit we have $f(\lambda)=\sup\{f(\eta): \eta<\lambda\}$.

If so, then the key point is bulletpoint $(ii)$: by restricting the range we prevent exactly the situation you're worried about. If, for example, the smallest element $\alpha$ of $M$ is greater than $\kappa$, we have $f(0)=\alpha>\kappa$ - and thus $f$ can't be $\kappa$-normal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the book, for an order preserving partial function $f$ from $On$ to $On$ is $\kappa$-continuous if $dom(f)$ is closed in $\kappa$ and $sup f[U] = f(sup U)$ for all $U\subseteq dom(f) \cap\kappa$ such that $|U|<\kappa$. And then such $f$ is $\kappa$-normal if $\kappa\subseteq dom(f)$. I think this definition is different from your suggestion, so should I think a standard definition of $\kappa$-normal is more restricted and the description of the book is mere mistake?

Comment: @nyaantech That looks like it might be the case.